# How do I find /dev/X in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, usb, usb-modem

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and trying to setup a Huawei K5150.
I installed usb_modeswitch and managed to make the device recognized as modem:

```
Mar 19 04:19:54 b kernel: [ 9796.066298] usb 1-5: USB disconnect, device number 2
Mar 19 04:19:54 b kernel: [ 9796.438807] usb 1-5: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
Mar 19 04:19:55 b kernel: [ 9796.572431] usb 1-5: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=1575
Mar 19 04:19:55 b kernel: [ 9796.572437] usb 1-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=5, Product=4, SerialNumber=0
Mar 19 04:19:55 b kernel: [ 9796.572440] usb 1-5: Product: K5150
Mar 19 04:19:55 b kernel: [ 9796.572444] usb 1-5: Manufacturer: Vodafone (Huawei)
Mar 19 04:19:55 b kernel: [ 9796.639247] cdc_ether 1-5:1.0 eth0: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-0000:00:1d.7-5, CDC Ethernet Device, 58:2c:80:13:92:63
Mar 19 04:19:55 b kernel: [ 9796.639292] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ether
Mar 19 04:19:55 b kernel: [ 9796.650152] cdc_ether 1-5:1.0 enx582c80139263: renamed from eth0
```

and

```
ifconfig enx582c80139263
enx582c80139263 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 58:2c:80:13:92:63  
      BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

but:

```
ls -l /sys/bus/usb-serial/devices
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Mar 19 07:15 ttyUSB0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.0/ttyUSB0
```

and

```
udevadm info --name=/dev/ttyUSB0
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.0/ttyUSB0/tty/ttyUSB0
N: ttyUSB0
S: rfxcom
...
```

which is another device.

How do I get a device for (/dev/X) for the K5150?

Comment: You don't, since it's recognized as a network device.

Comment: Ok. I want to use this modem with smstools as a sms gateway. As I understand, this should be possible. How can I make it happen? Forcing Ubuntu to not create a network interface and create a device instead?

Comment: It's not a matter of the OS. The *device itself* is identifying as a NIC. You need to tell the device to switch modes somehow, assuming that's even possible in the first place.

Comment: Ok. I see. Have to google a bit more. Thanks.